# Unresponsive apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, timeout

We host our web-service on a dedicated server.

During high-load period, the server returns a time-out error instead of a page very frequently.

We have around 170,000 daily requests.

However, server has a lot of free memory and the CPU is not loaded at the moment.

I cannot understand why the server works poor.

I have profiled the problem case with tcpdump utility. These are the good and bad sessions traced by tcpdump. The request is the same in both experiments.

`Good - server returns response.`

`Bad - no response, time-out error.`

Do you see why the problem happens from these data?
How can I move further to get closer to the source of the error?

I've replaced my real ip address with 123.45.67.890

```
---- Bad ----
12:23:36.366292 IP 123.45.67.890.61749 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: S 2125316338:2125316338(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK>
12:23:39.362394 IP 123.45.67.890.61749 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: S 2125316338:2125316338(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK>
12:23:45.365567 IP 123.45.67.890.61749 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: S 2125316338:2125316338(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK>
--------

---- Good ----
12:27:07.632229 IP 123.45.67.890.63914 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: S 3581365570:3581365570(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK>
12:27:10.620946 IP 123.45.67.890.63914 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: S 3581365570:3581365570(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK>
12:27:10.620969 IP myserver.superbservers.com.www > 123.45.67.890.63914: S 2654770980:2654770980(0) ack 3581365571 win 5840 <mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 6>
12:27:10.838747 IP 123.45.67.890.63914 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: . ack 1 win 4380
12:27:10.957143 IP 123.45.67.890.63914 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: P 1:213(212) ack 1 win 4380
12:27:10.957152 IP myserver.superbservers.com.www > 123.45.67.890.63914: . ack 213 win 108
12:27:10.965543 IP myserver.superbservers.com.www > 123.45.67.890.63914: P 1:630(629) ack 213 win 108
12:27:10.965621 IP myserver.superbservers.com.www > 123.45.67.890.63914: F 630:630(0) ack 213 win 108
12:27:11.183540 IP 123.45.67.890.63914 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: . ack 631 win 4222
12:27:11.185657 IP 123.45.67.890.63914 > myserver.superbservers.com.www: F 213:213(0) ack 631 win 4222
12:27:11.185663 IP myserver.superbservers.com.www > 123.45.67.890.63914: . ack 214 win 108
--------
```

Details on the service.

This is a weather reporting service.
It is written in Perl, backed by MySQL.
The script uses several modules (from CPAN and our own).

The code is relatively simple.
The script downloads the weather from another server, converts data format and returns XML response. The weather is cached in MyISAM DB.
There is a world locations data-base (INNODB) that can also be requested via the script.

These are the metrics taken during the high-load period.

Average traffic: 3MBit/sec

Average packets number: 3300 packets/sec

Hoster: SuperbHosting

OS: Ubuntu

Server parameters:
E6300 CONROE 1.86GHZ 2 X 1MB CACHE 1066
1GB DDR2 667MHZ

This is a link to apache configuration file we use
http://repkin5.snow.prohosting.com/apache.txt

This is server-status report taken right after time-out error.
http://repkin5.snow.prohosting.com/server-status.htm
There are only 10 Child Servers running out of 120, so enough space for new requests.

Top program snapshot during high-load period.

```
------
top - 13:21:29 up 15 days, 18:36,  1 user,  load average: 0.18, 0.19, 0.21
Tasks: 137 total,   1 running, 136 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.8%us,  1.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 92.8%id,  0.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  3.5%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1033904k total,   590620k used,   443284k free,     6892k buffers
Swap:  3028212k total,    82556k used,  2945656k free,    64156k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 4252 mysql     20   0  162m  48m 3352 S    1  4.8 279:01.27 mysqld
14503 www-data  20   0 43280  14m 3824 S    1  1.4   0:00.16 apache2
14577 www-data  20   0 43012  13m 3500 S    1  1.4   0:00.06 apache2
14401 www-data  20   0 45076  17m 4340 S    0  1.8   0:00.46 apache2
14414 www-data  20   0 45516  18m 4344 S    0  1.8   0:00.47 apache2
14420 www-data  20   0 45624  18m 4372 S    0  1.8   0:00.61 apache2
14421 www-data  20   0 45488  18m 4352 S    0  1.8   0:00.42 apache2
14496 www-data  20   0 44820  17m 4328 S    0  1.7   0:00.18 apache2
14510 www-data  20   0 45216  17m 4300 S    0  1.8   0:00.62 apache2
    1 root      20   0  2844  456  404 S    0  0.0   0:05.24 init
    2 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.24 migration/0
    4 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  32:28.85 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.77 watchdog/0
    6 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.15 migration/1
    7 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:03.07 ksoftirqd/1
    8 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.63 watchdog/1
-----
```

Answer (score 1):

We have sometime a strange behavior with a server that is very cool ("uptime" will tell you) but becomes very irresponsive. One way to check is to use "netstat", see how many lines you have. You can try Apache mod_status too. Our problem is still not very clear but it certainly comes from the outside world, ie the datacenter connectivity. A machine near you could be eating all bandwidth, or even filtering the packets before they arrive to you, thus the perceived slowness.

Not sure if it applies to you, but you apparently have not a high load on CPUs while a lot of apache processes waiting for something, maybe they wait for answers from outside... If you have "sar" it can help too.

Comment: Thanks, the Apache processes are waiting for 15 seconds for the next HTTP request from the same client. We have set KeepAlive option is on. It really makes our clients to work faster.

Comment: netstat gives me 5-10 lines per second at the peak time, but I don't know is it good or bad or what should I do. mod_status didn't help me to find the source of the problem also :(

Answer (score 1):

What's not been describe is what this web service is actually *designed/written to do*. Often application code running in simultaneous threads may form some level of contention for common resources or waiting for some backend resource that is bottleneck. Therefore even though memory or processor utilisation may not be high, the limitation of these other common resources may stall or delay the processing, thereby the timely response, of other threads.

What application platform is sitting on top of Apache to accomplish the work? as well as the end-most resource point required to service the web service request? If a backend database is involved, a query deadlock is probable in the database server.

Comment: icelava, thank you! I have updated the question with the details on our service. In short: Perl + MySQL = XML. The script downloads data, reads/writes to DB and prints XML on output. I know very few about MySQL administration. Is there a simple way to test if deadlocks occure on DB?

Comment: I just have installed innotop monitor. It has not displayed any deadlocks while I was catching "bad" case. So I assume DB deadlock is not the cause of error. May you suggest what else should I check to locate the source of the error?

Comment: innotop also displays this statistics, isn't it too high?
40.10 Queries per second, 56 threads

Answer (score 0):

There are two sections in your /etc/apache2/apache.conf file under mpm_prefork_module and mpm_worker_module

```
StartServers          5  
MinSpareServers       5  
MaxSpareServers      10  
MaxClients          150    
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
```

You might have to fine tune this sections according to your environment to handle more requests.

Comment: Thanks, Apache 2.0 doc says that StartServers, MinSpareServer MaxSpareServers will not change server performance much nowadays. We have MaxClients set to 120 and the number of requests never rises above this level. So there seem nothing to do with these knobs for us.